# Round off 4.54545454545455 to an integer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a to sum the values which are adjacent to "Leave" valued cell.These values are like  4.54545454545455 and on.
Since "leave" comes intermittently I use condition and accordingly store values from adjacent cell in redefined Integer array(Redim based on the number of occurrences of "Leave". 
 
Now I am summing that array here lies the problem as sum is coming up something like 13.409091E-02 and only ULong(which does not work in my VBA editor) can store values like this as much I researched and know. So, Datatypes like Long, Double are not able to store such a value.Which is giving a sum not asked.
 
 Is there any way this could work or Is there any other way such that I can check intermittent adjacent values to"Leave"and sum them.

```
Dim leavearray() As Long <br/>dim xsum as long<br/>dim counter3 as Integer<br/>dim colum as Integer<br/>dim ro as Integer<br/>dim ctr as Integer<br/>dim change as Integer

For counter3 = colum To ro<br/>
If Cells(counter3, 29) = "Leave" Then<br/>
ctr = ctr + 1<br/>
ReDim leavearray(ctr - 1)<br/>
Else<br/>
End If<br/>
Next counter3<br/><br/>For counter = colum To ro<br/>
If Cells(counter, 29) = "Leave" Then<br/>
change = change + 1<br/>
leavearray(change - 1) = Cells(counter, 30).Value 'stores value like 3.409091E-02 in array as and when "leave" occurs in its adjacent cell.<br/>
Else<br/>
End If<br/>
 If counter = ro Then<br/>
xsum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(leavearray)'It Stores 0 where the problem lies.
```

Comment: Please change the title of your problem. It should be specific and related to the problem!

Comment: Please add all your variable declarations to the posted code

Comment: Dim leavearray(), xsum As Long
Dim counter, ctr, s, change As Integer
Dim a As String
Dim counter1, counter2, counter3, c, ro, colum As Integer
Dim var As Variant

Comment: `xsum` should be a Double.

Comment: My VBA editor does not take ULong as a Dimension. Otherwise,probably this problem would have been solved.

Comment: No double did not worked.I have already tried using it.

Comment: Inspect the variables in debug mode and find out where the number is incorrect. Explicitly cast your worksheet values to `long`

Comment: `Dim counter1, counter2, counter3, c, ro, colum As Integer` - only `column` is Integer - all the others are Variants

Comment: After xsum things go wrong,it stores a 0.

Comment: a=CInt(Cells(counter,30)) leavearray(change - 1) = a. Used this expression for type conversion of values before storing it in an array.But this showed me error. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a number and wants only the integer part of it, you should use the command Int(), if you want it to be rounded, use CInt(), as shown in the code below:

```
Dim integerResult As Integer
Dim singleVariable As Single
singleVariable = 4.65

integerResult = Int(singleVariable)
MsgBox (integerResult)

integerResult = CInt(singleVariable)
MsgBox (integerResult)
```

The first MessageBox will show you 4, and the second MessageBox will show you 5.

Comment: Unleash, this should solve your problem but, please, next time, be more specific on your questions

Comment: Thanks for your time but it did not work variable single datatype stores  value 3.409091E-02. But Cint() line stores 0 in the integer variable.

Comment: @unleash That is entirely correct. 0.03409091 is 0 as integer

Comment: Well, let's make it clearer for him to understand. Unleash, I am not sure you are familiar with the number you showed, although, it is represented in the scientific notation, which means that, the number is 3.409091 x 10 ^ -02, or 0.03409091. If you convert it to integer, you will get 0. Got it?

Comment: Yeah !! Exactly, I figured that out !! Thanks a lot for your time.:)